# Why is my left join not working in my php mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to create an sql query that will show me the prices of the services selected by one user within a reservation.

So I want to select the `id_service` column from my table `chosen_services` where the `id_reservation` coresponds to the `$_SESSION['idReservation']` and get the price of these services and finaly calculate the total.

here are my 2 tables in mysql : https://ibb.co/NtgLLh7 and https://ibb.co/jkB0Qm6

Here's my query for the moment :

```
$getPriceOfAllServices = $bdd->prepare(
    'SELECT id_service 
    FROM CHOSEN_SERVICES 
    LEFT JOIN SERVICES ON CHOSEN_SERVICES.id_chosen_service = SERVICES.id_service 
    WHERE id_reservation = ?'
);
$getPriceOfAllServices->execute(array($_SESSION['idReservation']));
$getPriceOfAllServices = $getPriceOfAllServices->fetch();
```

And I have this error : https://ibb.co/Wc1hLvz

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please translate error message to English and add the message and sample data directly in body of your post not as [image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1422451).

Answer (score 0):

> `SELECT id_service`

Both tables involved in the query have a column called `id_service`. Since you did not prefix the column name, MySQL cannot reliably tell which of the two you mean, hence it raises the 'ambiguous column name` error.

Since you are using `LEFT JOIN`, it is very likely that you want to return the column coming from table `CHOSEN_SERVICES` (since the other column might be `NULL`, when the join condition does not match).

Consider:

```
SELECT CHOSEN_SERVICES.id_service 
FROM CHOSEN_SERVICES 
LEFT JOIN SERVICES ON CHOSEN_SERVICES.id_chosen_service = SERVICES.id_service 
WHERE id_reservation = ?
```

---

NB: please note that column `id_reservation` in the `WHERE` clause is not prefixedeither. While this will not generate the same error (since that column only exists in one of the two tables), it is a good practice to *always* prefix columns when several tables are involved. Another good habit is to use table aliases.

Accordingly here is a new version of your query:

```
SELECT cs.id_service 
FROM chosen_services cs
LEFT JOIN services s ON cs.id_chosen_service = s.id_service 
WHERE cs.id_reservation = ?
```